# Best ways to collect ELB access logs into Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-elb

ELB access logs are stored on S3 buckets.  I've been researching but have been unable to find some good examples of how to get these logs into Cloudwatch.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Greg

Comment: So no one has ever done this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to trigger events when the S3 bucket receives log streams and send it directly to CloudWatch metrics or Cloudwatch events using a Lambda.

I'm not sure if it is the best approach. I'll investigate and update the answer.